# unable to push and append data to the state using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here i  state  with data

```
state = {
    Response: [
      {
        "id": "15071",
        "name": "John",
        "salary": "53",
        "age": "23",
        "department": "admin"
      },
      {
        "id": "15072",
        "name": "maxr",
        "salary": "53",
        "age": "23",
        "department": "admin"
      },
      {
        "id": "15073",
        "name": "Josef",
        "salary": "53",
        "age": "23",
        "department": "admin"
      },
      {
        "id": "15074",
        "name": "Ye",
        "salary": "53",
        "age": "23",
        "department": "admin"
      }
    ]
```

i am displaying these records in the table. In table u will see 10 records and there will be a button on top of table so if append button is pressed then 10 records has to be added on every button press and the data has to be same but it has to be appended using the below logic i am trying to set the state by pushing 10 records and trying to append it  for ex if i have  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 if i press append 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  has to be apeended

```
appendEmployees() {
  var reLoadCount = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const myObj = {
      id: 0,
      name: '',
      salary: 0,
      department: ''
    };
    myObj.id = +this.setState.employee[i].id + (reLoadCount * 10);
    myObj.name = this.setState.employee[i].name;
    myObj.salary = this.setState.employee[i].salary;
    myObj.department = this.setState.employee[i].department;
    this.setState.employee.push(myObj);
  }
  reLoadCount++;
}
```

am i doing some thing wrong here

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you want to achieve? Try and break down the question and make it logical. Presently the way it is asked is very confusing.

Comment: `myObj.department = this..setState.employee[i].department;` <-- There is double `..`

Comment: @Eddie  updated question please check

Comment: The double `.` is still on line `myObj.department = this..setState.employee[i].department;`

Comment: [`setState` is a function, not an object](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which is essentially the most impportant and most basic bit of React API you need to know, so I can recommend shelving what you're doing and first actually learning "how to do React" by following the most excellent tutorial on the React website itself. It takes an hour, two if you're playing around, and is entirely worth running through if you're new to React, _or_ if you've used old versions of React and need a refresher.

Comment: (basically the way you're trying to update state in this code is wrong on enough levels for the answer to really be "take the tutorial (again)" because you have JS syntax errors, you're using setState apparently without ever having checked how it's supposed to work, and you're using an asynchronous update mechanism in sequential code and clearly expect that to work, so while this code is _all kinds of  bad_, the real problem is that you need to go back the beginning and (re)learn how to actually use React)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i am new to react and may i know what is the exact issue with below or suggestion for change

Comment: Not from me, no: however, you can teach yourself what's wrong with your code by opening https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, and then doing that tutorial. It's extremely well written, it teaches you exactly how things work, and why, and what functions you want/need to call when you want/need to do certain things. If you're new to React, _take that tutorial_ first, because it makes no sense to start asking questions about React and why your own code inventions don't work if you've never even taken the React intro. It's there for a reason, and teaches how to use React right in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right you're trying to add 10 duplicates of the objects in the `this.state.employee` array, the only difference between these new objects and the existing ones is their `id`.

If that is the case, here is how you can do that:

```
appendEmployees() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    // Get the biggest ID number.
    const maxId = Math.max(...prevState.employee.map(e => parseInt(e.id)));
    // create 10 new employees copies of the first 10.
    const newEmployees = prevState.employee.slice(0, 10).map((e, i) => ({
      ...e,
      id: (maxId + i + 1)
    }));
    // return/update the state with a new array for "employee" that is a concatenation of the old array and the array of the 10 new ones.
    return {
      employee: [...prevState.employee, ...newEmployees]
    }
  });
}
```

I've added some comments to the example to explain what it does.

The important thing is `this.setState` which is the function used to update the state, here, I've used it with a function as the first parameter (it works with objects as well), I've did that because it is the preferred way of generating a new state that is derived from the old state.

Comment: Ok now for the updating the new records also i have a post request  so i have to send employee  as body ? or any other thing ?

Comment: @Dexter If you pass a function as the second argument to `setState`, it will be executed when the new state is set and will have the new state as a parameter, eg: `this.setState(prevState => {}, newState => {/*access the new state, make API calls*/})`

Comment: got it i have to send the this.state.employee  as i will get the all updated records to the post body then right